# Leverage Browser caching django-nginx not working

Tags: python, django, caching, nginx

I prepare a django project with server engine nginx using gunicorn for that. I am trying to work out page insights and I want to leverage browser caching in my nginx settings.

My directory layout of project is:

```
mainprojectfolder
--mainproject
----static
manage.py
--media_cdn
--static_cdn
```

In my settings.py I arranged static files :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/static_cdn/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/media_cdn/"
```

My nginx settings are

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.ozkandurakoglu.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    root /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/;
    access_log /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/logs/nginx-access.log;
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/ozkand/static/;
     }

    location /media/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/media_cdn/;
      ;
    }


    #location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    #               expires 365d;
    #       }
}
```

when I comment out cache , all my static and media files gets 404 and nothing is shown. can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this link and it should work**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/leverage-browser-caching-for-nginx

[image]

Comment: there is nothing I see wrong about location directive , It is under server block.

Comment: please post an answer, not just an link to a possible solution which could be offline in some days (yes it's DO, it propably will not be offline in the next few days - but I think you get it)

Comment: check this one.

Comment: what is wrong with my code ? I see the same code in my server block, I dont get the difference with link you have sent?